# How to assign the deleted data of an in-memory table to a variable?

Tags: select, sql-delete, dolphindb

I want to assign the deleted data of table t to variable a as follows:

```
a = delete from t where t1 > 0
```

If there is no variable assignment, the specified data of t is directly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the select statement to assign values to a. Here is an example script:

```
a=select * from where t1>0
delete from where t1>0
```